# Communication Link Failure While Connecting AWS RDS to JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc

I was trying to connect my java project with MySQL database in Amazon RDS, when I try to connect, it seems that
[image]

the error shows like
[image]

```
package main;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Connect {
 
  public static Connection connect(){
       try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://pharmacy1.c2ew5dbqpxab.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/pharmacy","<username>","<password>");
    if(con!=null)return con ;
   }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(),"Error",2);
   }
   return null ;
}    
  }
```

I have searched google, can't find any solution.

Comment: You need to update your mysql connector. What version do you have? you can get different versions from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/. What version of mysql do you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect from your local machine, you have to add your local machine's IP in Inbound Rule under Security Group from RDS Console.